# Cannot get C++ code running

Tags: c++

Here is the simple code. I cant figure out why the code would compile but not run. I tried CodeBlocks and DevC++. non worked.

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, you probably are doing something wrong when running it, because this compiles.

Comment: We can't figure it out either. There's not enough information in the question.

Comment: I pretty sure I am doing it right. But maybe I need to change something in the settingof the Compiler itself. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: It just would not work. My question is why would it compile but not run? In codeblocks, the error states that "iostream: no such file or directory"

Comment: It means that you have not set up the IDE properly. Consult the user manual.

Comment: I suspect that you're misunderstanding some of the words you're using.  The error you quote implies that it did **not** compile.

Comment: But in DevC++ nothing goes wrong. It does not say if there is something worng. And It compiles fine. Just does not run.

Comment: In DevC++, try adding this line before the `return 0`: `system("PAUSE")`

Comment: where do i find the users manual?

Comment: great! The Pause helped. It runs now. Do you know what the issue could be? This is weird I think

Comment: The compiler included with DevC++ has had this issue for years. I'm not sure what compiler it is, but the code you posted does run, but window disappears as soon as it does, and you need a pause to be able to see it.

Comment: because the cout does not print anything on the screen. The only thing I see is press any key...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <windows.h>
   int main()
   {
     cout<<"hi";
     system("pause");//to hold console window
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is absolutely correct and it compiles too. Make sure you are saving the file with **.cpp** extension. DevC++ works perfectly fine, there is no issue with the compiler.